# IFileOpenDialog access violation

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, com, access-violation

I am using Windows 7 64-bit and Visual Studio C++ 2017 Community. I am trying to create a Windows open file dialog using `IFileOpenDialog`, but I keep getting these two access violation errors when the program ended:

```
Exception thrown at 0x00000000771ED1CB (ntdll.dll) in p.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x0000000000000074.

Exception thrown at 0x00000000771DDC9D (ntdll.dll) in p.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x0000000000000074.
```

In an attempt to debug the access violations, I commented everything out and copied code from [Microsoft's online example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff485843(v=vs.85).aspx), but the error would not go away. It seemed to be caused by `pFileOpen->Show(NULL);` call. However, I ended up creating a new project, and put the same code in, and voila, it worked! This is what the example looked like :

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <shobjidl.h> 

int main()
{
    HRESULT hr = CoInitializeEx(NULL, COINIT_APARTMENTTHREADED | 
        COINIT_DISABLE_OLE1DDE);
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        IFileOpenDialog *pFileOpen;

        // Create the FileOpenDialog object.
        hr = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_FileOpenDialog, NULL, CLSCTX_ALL, 
                IID_IFileOpenDialog, reinterpret_cast<void**>(&pFileOpen));

        if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
        {
            // Show the Open dialog box.
            hr = pFileOpen->Show(NULL); <-------**Culprit**

            // Get the file name from the dialog box.
            if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
            {
                IShellItem *pItem;
                hr = pFileOpen->GetResult(&pItem);
                if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
                {
                    PWSTR pszFilePath;
                    hr = pItem->GetDisplayName(SIGDN_FILESYSPATH, &pszFilePath);

                    // Display the file name to the user.
                    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
                    {
                        MessageBox(NULL, pszFilePath, L"File Path", MB_OK);
                        CoTaskMemFree(pszFilePath);
                    }
                    pItem->Release();
                }
            }
            pFileOpen->Release();
        }
        CoUninitialize();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

So, I checked through both projects property pages, since my original project had GLFW and GLEW libraries linked, so maybe they were to blame. Once I removed them and made sure both property pages looked the same (eg: they were including the same libs), the error in my original project would not go away.

If anyone has any idea why this is happening, any help would be appreciated.

Also note, this isn't preventing the program from running, I would just like to get rid of it.

Comment: It is not uncommonly caused by code that you don't know about.  Shell extensions that get loaded into your process, there are a lot of bad ones out there and a programmer's Win7 machine had a lot of time to accumulate cruft.  You have to show the stack trace to get help.

Comment: Is this a first-chance exception, or a second-chance exception? If it's a first-chance exception, just ignore it. Someone raised it, and someone handled it. Simply move on. Someone screwed up, and someone else was prepared for someone else screwing up.

Answer (score -1):

Do you have the 0xc0000005 exception checked under debug->windows->exception Settings in the win32 group? I only get the behavior you describe if I do have that checked. And in particular if I look at the call stack the exception is in     ValidateTreeItem.
I am not aware of any way to not get that behavior if you do have break on throw enabled for 0xC0000005.